# Out-front mount screw for Garmin Edge 540/840/1040

Tags: bike-computer, garmin

I realise this might be a pretty long shot but I'll try anyway: please, does anyone know the dimensions of the screw that secures the out-front mount of Garmin Edge 540 (and possibly 840 and 1040) to the handle bar? It's the "1" in following picture: [image: this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This thread](https://forums.garmin.com/sports-fitness/cycling/f/varia-series/246562/bolt-size-for-varia-quarter-turn-mount) on the Garmin support forum gives the size as:

> socket head cap screw M3 0.5 x 14